# How End a thread conformation

Tags: c#

So I'm still fairly new to C#.
So far I would like to know how to check if a thread has ended. I know that i can put a bool at the end of the method the thread uses and use that to determine if the thread ends.. but i dont want to do that, mainly because i want to learn the right way
so far I have this.

```
Thread testThreadd = new Thread(Testmethod);
testThreadd.Start();
testThreadd.Join();
```

I read about the thread.join(); class. To my understanding, that class only prevents any code after that from executing.. Please help.
thanks

Comment: `join()` actually joins the thread with the current executing thread. Though, what your explaining is right, it's just the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are different ways that give different results
1 ) Wait until the work has finished. This is exactly what you've got with your code already. You'll start a thread and then wait for that thread to finish before continuing execution.

```
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

2) thread.ThreadState will tell you whether or not the thread has finished. In a basic scenario you could do the following. This would allow you to check the current thread state at any point in your code where you've got access to the state.

```
if(thread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running){
   // Thread has stopped
```

}
3) Using an event. A lot of Async examples will start some work and then trigger an event once the work has been completed. In this way you can sit watching for an event and respond once the work has completed. A usage example may look like the WebClient class

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new
 AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for [Thread.IsAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried is a right way to wait for a thread to be done. But:

1. `Thread.Join()` is a function of `Thread` class.
2. Calling `Join()` function of a thread instance (in your sample `testThreadd`) will make the current thread to wait until `testThreadd` finishes it's job. Current thread is the thread which is calling `testThreadd.Join()`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the supplied answers, these days, the most used method would be by using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task). Besides having all the Wait and IsCompleted possibilities, these have the added advantage of having a [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd270696) method

start a task

```
var task = Task.Run((Action)TestMethod);
```

check completed

```
    if (task.IsCompleted) { }
```

wait for task to finish (same as thread.sleep)

```
    task.Wait();
```

setting a continuewith (additional task to be started after the task finishes)

```
    var task = new Task((Action)TestMethod); 
    task.ContinueWith(t => MessageBox.Show("Finished"));
    task.Start();
```

and combined, waiting for the continued task to finish (which automatically means, the first task is finished)

```
    var task = new Task((Action)TestMethod); 
    var continuedtask = task.ContinueWith(t => MessageBox.Show("Finished"));
    task.Start();
    continuedtask.Wait();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) instead of manually starting a new thread. It raises the `RunWorkerCompleted` event if its work is done (or if an exception occurs).

Comment: Links are not consider as answers